# Java RESTful - "Not Found" error

Tags: java, rest, weblogic

I am trying to deploy an *.ear application in a WebLogic Server.
All the implementation, the DataSource creation were good. But when I access the link to return the `localhost` data in `json`, it returns `Not Found` on the page's body. Like this:
[image]

This only happens when the application should return data from the server. If I access a URL that returns a HTML it works fine.
[image]

**Detail**
This is happening **only** now that I am implementing in another WebLogic Server. When I was running on my local machine's WebLogic Server, it works fine.

EDIT<\B>

My server log: ``` <Warning> <JAX-RS Integration> Cannot add Jersey Servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackageResourceConfig because ApplicationPath Annotation is not set on it``<Warning><Socket> Closing the socket, asw no data read from it at 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62.645 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds ```

Comment: Maybe the entity/resource simply doesn't exist. Did you debug the application?

Comment: @Thomas When I was creating the DataSources in WebLogic, the tests were all ok. What do you mean?

Comment: Did you check the datasource contains the data you're looking for? Are you sure you're using the correct datasource? Did you debug the application to check why it returns "Not found" (most probably a 404)? Or might the webservice not have been deployed (should probably be shown in the logs)?

Comment: @Thomas At the server that the error in occurring I have only deployed the *.ear application on it. Can I debug from there? Because, like I said, in my machine (where the application was developed) it works fine.

Comment: First, do you know if your application is actually being called? It's possible that the application is returning a 404 but it's also possible that the URL you're using is somehow triggering the application server not to route the request to the application. If the problem is within your application you should look for exceptions in the logs, or cases where the code turns a response from (e.g.) a DB query into a response.

Comment: I have checked and done some tests and it really seems to be returning 404. But how come it does work in my computer, and ther it doesn't? Because the DataSources name are the same as mine, also the databases name.

Comment: Have you checked your application servers logs? Are there any exceptions in there? Is there a load balancer or any other network infrastructure sitting in front of your remote instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have the `Jersey` and `JAX` libs deployed in my WebLogic installation.
In the current latest Weblogic version you cannot deploy these two libs together, because they have the same name.
Solved that by installing an older version, deploying the libs and my RESTful Service workes fine.